# Being hired for fortune 500 company via another technical service provider

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process, job-offer, ethics, pakistan

In countries like Pakistan, there are companies which do project-based hiring and as soon as projects are finished, so are the jobs.

**Process of hiring:**

1. Get Project From a fortune 500 or big company.
2. Post the jobs on local websites
3. Then offering them offshore software development and letting them interview the candidate and short list.
4. Collect the CV
5. Asking his/her expected salary (Same salary package is passed to clients which are mostly from USA)
6. CLient interviews and hight the candiate inderctly.

**Catch:**

1. Candidate is asked to share his/her CV in word format
2. Showing the client He is currently working with US (In Actuall, candidate is still working in current company, if hired then he is offered a job in middle company.)
3. Candidate is told to tell the client that your current job is with this company.
4. If hired, middle company hires the candidate for the compnay.
5. Client company is shown that they have many resource and available on request.

I am going through same thing, if I tell you for which company I am being contacted, you won't believe, It's from US. They have also development office here, but they never contacted my because of politics and social class differences. I have applied a few times, but never heard from them, but getting hired from their head-office is kind a sad.

Anyways what do you think, should I be part of this lie?

Don't you think that fortune 500 company is responsible for all this? why don't they hire from their Pakistani software office?

I wonder if they know how candidate is selected and that lie, which i told you about.

I am just proceeding how it all happens and not much interested. I would be if they would have giving me a chance in their own company and I would be really proud.

**Questions:**

1. How to proceed with such jobs and companies?
2. Why even fortune 500 company would hire resources like that and stays blind that how candidate is chooses for it?
3. How such companies get contacts in these companies?
4. Where are the morals of such companies who spoil the market for candidates.
5. I am wondering should I tell the fortune 500 company that how I am being hired for them and what impact it would have on my career as the local hiring firm have all the personal details about me?
6. Showing the client that candidate is currently working with contractor (In Actual, candidate is still working in his current other company, if hired then he is offered a job in middle company.), How bad is this and how US company will see it. I wonder if they don't know these practices. What is your take and experience on that

Looking forward to hear from you soon.

Thanks.

Note: Best of the best is hired and client makes sure itself.

Comment: We want to give you answers that are actionable. But your question is not phrased in a way that allows us to give us answers that you can act upon. Rephrase with your question with this standard in mind: "What is it that you want us to advise you on what to do?" Remember, we can help you navigate you navigate the issues you encounter in the workplace (up to a point). We don't do research and we certainly don't influence hiring policies in any country.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I personally don't like the idea of being hired for just a project and then being thrown as a toilet paper. Because companies which hire candidate, tomorrow they change their name and start again. I am well aware and just want to experience from inside. I am totally against it.

Comment: "Why don't they hire from their Pakistani software office?" - Honest answer?  its likely more work to transfer people that live in  Pakistan to the U.S. then it is to find somebody already in the U.S.

Comment: I have no idea, i am told, their USA office will conduct and short list the candidate. In their local people Pakistani elites work. It's mean English speaking and family status should be high and you should only be from local top 3 most expensive universities. Otherwise your CV is thrown away and don't stand a chance here.

Answer (score 3):

This is all about contracts and the expectations between customers and thier contractors.

First, lets talk about terminology.  When a company wins a contract with a customer, they are called the "prime contractor" or simply the "prime". The prime is assumed to have a number of other companies they do business with called the "subcontractors" or simply the "subs".

Whenever a major company asks the business community if they can do some work as a contractor, that request is called a "Request for Proposal" or simply an "RFP. There are a number of terms for the responses, so generally, it is called a "RFP response", or simply the "response".

Ok, now that the terms are out of the way, lets talk about the circumstances that make the above happen, and more importantly when it is legal and when it is not.

When I need to have a lot of work done on my house, I will put a notice in the paper for the work I need done and a number of general contactors will respond with bids. These are the primes.  When I accept one of thier terms, I expect that they will hire companies that can do specific bits of the job (electrical, plumbing, carpentry, etc). The prime accepts most of the liability for the performance of the subs.

As a homeowner, I must trust the general contractor (prime) to select good folks (subs) to do the specialized work the general contactor can't. When they do, I am legally forbidden from going to a plumber and telling them exactly how to do thier job. Instead, I have to tell the general contactor (prime) when I have an issue with the sub.  The reason for this is liability. If the prime hires a sub that underperforms, I punish the prime by withholding payment or seeking legal remedies for liability.  The prime then goes after the sub to seek thier liability.

The notion that I, a customer, cannot direct a sub's work directly is called "privity of contract", and if I violate it, the prime is no longer liable for anything the sub does.  As a customer, I want as much of the burden of liability on the prime as possible, so I don't violate thier privity.

This holds true for large companies that win contracts to do work for customers; privity rules apply. Because of this any person on the prime's team is viewed by the customer as working for the prime. The customer usually doesn't care (and shouldn't care due to privity rules) who the actual employer is, as long as they meet the minimum necessary requirements of the position.